# Magento 2 Show out product atlast

Tags: magento2

How to show Show out product atlast in Magento 2

I followed this

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Model\Plugin;

class Layer
{

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject
     * @param $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterGetProductCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject, $collection)
    {


            $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                ['_inventory_table' => 'cataloginventory_stock_item'],
                "_inventory_table.product_id = e.entity_id",
                ['is_in_stock']
            );

            $collection->setOrder('is_in_stock', 'DESC');
            $collection->setOrder('created_at', 'DESC');
       //echo $collection->getSelect();
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and let me know

```
  $collection
   ->joinField('inventory_in_stock', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'is_in_stock', 'product_id=entity_id','is_in_stock>=0', 'left')
   ->setOrder('inventory_in_stock', 'desc');
```

Comment: NO It's not comming